# Polar Stereographic projection of geopandas world map

Tags: python, geopandas, cartopy

I want to use the geopandas included low resolution world map (see [here](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html)) as a background for my data. This works fine as long as I use e.g. 'PlateCarree' projection.

If I now want to use a polar stereographic peojection

```
ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
```

or

```
ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
```

It does not work.

My code looks like this (using python 3)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

crs = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
w = world.to_crs(crs_proj4)
w.plot(facecolor='sandybrown', edgecolor='black',)
```

Any idea if polar stereographic projections simply do not work for this map (if so why?) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting with a specific cartopy projection, it is best to actually create the matplotlib figure and axes using cartopy, to make sure it is aware of the projection (in technical terms: to make sure it is a `GeoAxes`, see https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/intro.html):

```
crs = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init
w = world.to_crs(crs_proj4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
w.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='sandybrown', edgecolor='black')
```

However, this still seems to plot the shapes that fall outside of the extent. Using the cartopy `add_geometries` method, this better respects the extent:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
ax.add_geometries(w['geometry'], crs=crs, facecolor='sandybrown', edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

This looks a bit strange at first sight (Antartica in the middle is very small), but this seems to be expected (see https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/projections.html#southpolarstereo).

In general, see the example on combining GeoPandas and cartopy in the docs: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/cartopy_convert.html

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. However this does not really solve my problem, as I not only need to plot using stereographic projection, but also want to have a blue (or any other coloured) ocean. Using this I sadly cannot achieve this. I will include this requirement into my original question.

Comment: Changing the problem after you got an answer is not really good. You might want to accept this answer as it solves one of your problems and ask a new questions with your new requirements added. In the future make sure to include all requirements right from the beginning to make it easier to give you the right solution to your problem.