# Geopandas world map in Polar Stereographic projection with coloured oceans

Tags: python, geopandas, cartopy

Adding a further requirement to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646598/polar-stereographic-projection-of-geopandas-world-map), I also need to have the oceans in blue (or any other colour).

For the 'PlateCarree' projection I can simply do this

```
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
w = world.to_crs(crs_proj4)
g = w.plot(facecolor='sandybrown', edgecolor='black')
```

And now adding the ocean colour

```
g.set_facecolor('#A8C5DD')
```

If I now want to use a polar stereographic peojection

```
ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
```

or

```
ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
```

the projection does not work. When applying the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646598/polar-stereographic-projection-of-geopandas-world-map), I cannot get the oceans coloured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot the map geometries on Cartopy `geoaxes`, and use `cartopy.feature.OCEAN` to plot the ocean. Here is the working code that you may try. Read the comments in the code for clarification.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy

facecolor = 'sandybrown'
edgecolor = 'black'
ocean_color = '#A8C5DD'

#crs1 = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
crs1 = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
w1 = world.to_crs(crs1.proj4_init)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7), subplot_kw={'projection': crs1})

# useful code to set map extent,
# --- if you want maximum extent, comment out the next line of code ---
ax1.set_extent([-60.14, 130.4, -13.12, -24.59], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# at maximum extent, the circular bound trims map features nicely
ax1.add_geometries(w1['geometry'], crs=crs1, \
                facecolor=facecolor, \
                edgecolor=edgecolor, \
                linewidth=0.5)

# this adds the ocean coloring
ax1.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor=ocean_color, edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

The output plot will be:

[image]