# Geopandas - map and locaton plotting

Tags: python, geopandas, cartopy

Thanks to the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651437/geopandas-world-map-in-polar-stereographic-projection-with-coloured-oceans) I can plot the geopandas world map with continents and oceans coloured in different projections.

Now I would like to add some points, e.g. the cities included in geopandas

```
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
```

Unfortunately the cities are covered by the filled continents. Is there a way to get these cities in front or on top of the map?

My current code looks like this:

```
facecolor = 'sandybrown'
edgecolor = 'black'
ocean_color = '#A8C5DD'

crs1 = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

w1 = world.to_crs(crs1.proj4_init)
c1 = cities.to_crs(crs1.proj4_init)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7), subplot_kw={'projection': crs1})

# useful code to set map extent,
# --- if you want maximum extent, comment out the next line of code ---
ax1.set_extent([-60.14, 130.4, -13.12, -24.59], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# at maximum extent, the circular bound trims map features nicely
ax1.add_geometries(w1['geometry'], crs=crs1, facecolor=facecolor, edgecolor=edgecolor, linewidth=0.5)

# this adds the ocean coloring
ax1.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor=ocean_color, edgecolor='none')

# this adds the cities
c1.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', color='red', markersize=50)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `zorder`, for example: `c1.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', color='red', markersize=50, zorder=20)` should bring all the points in front.

Comment: It can be so simple :). This did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default drawing order for `axes` is patches, lines, text. This order is determined by the zorder attribute.

```
Polygon/patch,  zorder=1
Line 2D,  zorder=2
Text,  zorder=3
```

You can change the order for individual map features by setting the `zorder`. 
Any individual plot() call can set a value for the zorder of that particular item.

In your case, the code

```
c1.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', color='red', markersize=50, zorder=20)
```

will plot the markers on top of all other features that have `zorder` less than 20.

Zorder demo: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html